# which is the REST URL to call to get custom application configuration?

Tags: jhipster

In my jhipster-registry-master/central-config/application.yml I have added my property.
Which is the REST URL te get it?

Answer (score 0):

http://127.0.0.1:8761/config/application.yml if you ran the registry locally with default settings.

This is useful only for debugging.

Make sure you read the [Spring Cloud Config Server documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html)